# git pre-receive-hook redirect branch

Tags: git

I know you can do tons of things in git hooks. But is it possible to redirect the push to a different branch.

Say I push from master, But in the hook script, I set up a new branch, and make this branch into the new branch without the pusher knowing about it. Is this possible within git?

Or I could manually check it into a new branch.But how do I not apply the changeset on requested branch and not returning error message(reject change but success message)?

Answer (score 0):

I've been investigating it some time ago. Unfortunately, the answer seems to be "No". The `pre-receive` hook cannot change the target branch. Moreover, the wire protocol does not report back to the pushing client the name of target branch, so even if you hack your server side to change the target branch from `foo` to `bar`, there is no way to let the pushing client know that it should update reference `origin/bar`, not `origin/foo`.

Comment: I was trying to implement something like `phabricator`'s diff mechanism without the use of `arcanist`. It creates a new temporary branch for every 'push'(not literally git push) whichever branch you push to. I'm wondering if this can be done in pure git protocol. I don't need client to update references. The problem is how can I not really apply the changesets, but return success messages to client.